# Retrieve data with foreach from return array function

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having troubles with my function and how to retrieve the data. Here is what i got.

```
public function getImages()
{
    $array = array();

    //Test query
    $query = $this->connect()->query("SELECT * from user");
    while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
        $array[] = $row;
        return $array;
    }
}
```

Now I'm calling this function but i can not use foreach to access the array.

```
include "header.html";
include "autoload.php";
spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');

$users = new User;
$users->getImages();

foreach ($users as $value) {
  echo $value["username"];
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm only getting one result but there are many in my database. Or if i call the $array in foreach it says undefined.

Comment: What is the code doing wrong? I assume you’re only getting one result. Look where your return statement is. And please always explain exactly what is wrong with the code so we don’t have to guess

Comment: You are right! I'm getting only one result.

Comment: I literally figured it out after I saw your comment! You are great! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A couple things.  First, your function is only ever returning an array with *one* element in it.  If you want to finish populating the array, don't return until after the loop:

```
while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
    $array[] = $row;
}
return $array;
```

And second, you're trying to iterate over the object which has the function, not the value returned from the function.  Get the return value and iterate over that:

```
$userDAO = new User;
$users = $userDAO->getImages();

foreach ($users as $value) {
    echo $value["username"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put the return statement out of the while loop.

```
public function getImages() { 
      $array = array(); //Test query
      $query = $this->connect()->query("SELECT * from user"); 
       while ($row = $query->fetch()) { 
            $array[] = $row; 
        }
        return $array;
  }
```